# Nested dictionary creation from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have a python text file as follows 
even;0;even;1;odd
odd;0;odd;1;even

After opening and reading this file I need to return a nested dictionary for which the outer level is the first word in each line and the inner dictionary has the next number as the key and the value next to it as the value... How would I be able to implement this using the zip function?

So for example the dict for the first line would look like this:
{even:{0: even, 1:odd}}

```
xref = defaultdict(dict)
for line in file:
    list = line.strip().split(';')
    for item in list: 
        xref[list[0]] = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and the foremost, you can not use `list` as a variable name because `list` is a keyword in python. That said, you are on right track. This is what you want:

```
>>> xref = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for line in file:
        alist = line.strip().split(';')
        zlist = alist[1:]
        xref[alist[0]] = dict(zip(zlist[::2], zlist[1::2]))


>>> xref
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'even': {'1': 'odd', '0': 'even'}, 'odd': {'1': 'even', '0': 'odd'}})
```

Note that the inner dictionary has the order of elements different than what you expected but elements in a dictionary are unordered by default.

Hope this helps.